# How do i keep the object to be moved only inside the background borders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

For now my object can move only right and left.
I want that if i move it to the right it will stop on the mose tight side border of the background image and same for left side.

The background:

```
X : 5.5  
Y : 3 
Z : 1
```

The object that i'm moving:

```
X : 1 
Y : 1 
Z : 1
```

This is the script i'm using now:

```
using UnityEngine;using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float movementSpeed = 10;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (transform.position.x <= -4.3f) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(-4.3f, transform.position.y);
        } else if (transform.position.x >= 4.3f) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(4.3f, transform.position.y);
        }

        if (transform.position.y <= -2.7f) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, -2.7f);
        } else if (transform.position.y >= 2.7f) {
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 2.7f);
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is with this part it's not stopping on the edges of right and left of the background:

```
if (transform.position.x <= -4.3f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(-4.3f, transform.position.y);
} else if (transform.position.x >= 4.3f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(4.3f, transform.position.y);
}

if (transform.position.y <= -2.7f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, -2.7f);
} else if (transform.position.y >= 2.7f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 2.7f);
}
```

Comment: The background is image not sprite

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how did you get the number 4.3?
If the background scale is 5.5, then it is extended to left and right with 2.75.
And then taking into account your object size (1,1,1) then you have to subtract it with half of your object size too.

```
// 2.25 = 5.5 / 2 (half of background scale) - 0.5 (half of object scale)
if (transform.position.x <= -2.25f) {  
    transform.position = new Vector2(-4.3f, transform.position.y);
} else if (transform.position.x >= 2.25f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(4.3f, transform.position.y);
}

if (transform.position.y <= -1f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, -2.7f);
} else if (transform.position.y >= 1f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 2.7f);
}
```

However a common way to limit movement of an object is usually done using [Mathf.clamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html). The code above can be shortened into only 1 line:

```
if (transform.position.x <= -2.25f) {  
    transform.position = new Vector2(-4.3f, transform.position.y);
} else if (transform.position.x >= 2.25f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(4.3f, transform.position.y);
}

if (transform.position.y <= -1f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, -2.7f);
} else if (transform.position.y >= 1f) {
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 2.7f);
}
```

Becomes:

```
transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, -2.25f, 2.25f), 
                                 Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.y, -1f, 1f));
```